# React-Native Networking Library- Gzip, Redirect and Caching

Tags: react-native, axios

Which React-Native Networking Library supports following features

1. Gzip response
2. Server redirects
3. Validates cached responses with ETags

among Axios and Fetch Api or any other for both android and ios platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,,,

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

for network calls